# Htop says "530G" in "VIRT" for "vagrant ssh"

Tags: macos, memory, vagrant, virtualbox, htop

I use Vagrant on a MacOS with an ubuntu64 16.04. Running `htop`, I can see `vagrant ssh` process can use virtually 530G (in `VIRT` Column).

Is it the normal behavior of Vagrant? Should I panic? Is it "normal" to have virtually 530G on a mac with 120G of disk and 16G of RAM? Or maybe did I not understand the meaning of `VIRT`?

The vagrant box runs on virtual box and has only 1G of RAM allocated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by [chrisroberts](https://github.com/chrisroberts) on [github](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7296):

> Hi! I was able to reproduce this behavior, but with any vagrant command executed. The vagrant ssh command is the easiest to see this behavior simply because the process is left running for as long as the ssh session is alive.
>
> **The tl;dr version of below is simply: Don't worry about it. VIRT isn't allocated memory. If it were, you would either need massive swap space, or nothing would be working.**
>
> So, what's going on here? The vagrant installer includes a small go executable (vagrant) whose job is to setup the current environment with the proper locations of everything it needs. The installers bin directory, the lib directory for ruby and all the other friends, all the gems, and the vagrant gem itself. Once it has all this configured, it spawns off a new process, the actual Ruby vagrant process.
>
> Because your example was referencing vagrant ssh, and as was previously pointed out ([#7296 (comment)](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7296#issuecomment-222270159)) a Kernel.exec happens meaning the Ruby process does not persist, I figured it must be the wrapper that was the culprit. After a bit of searching (mostly to find stackoverflow items saying "don't worry about VIRT") I stumbled upon:
>
> [keybase/keybase-issues#1908](https://github.com/keybase/keybase-issues/issues/1908)
>
> They refer to the golang FAQ that talks about a bunch of VIRT being claimed up front and it not being a big deal, but never any absolutes about how much was actually being claimed. A link to lwn was dropped in there ([keybase/keybase-issues#1908 (comment)](https://github.com/keybase/keybase-issues/issues/1908#issuecomment-164165217)) regarding golang's behavior on startup of claiming a huge chunk of VIRT, but still everything referenced a much lower amount than I was seeing locally. So I decided to go dig into the golang runtime code, and within malloc.go we find the answer:
>
> [golang src/runtime/malloc.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/aaf4099a5cabfee52b1c481f2a30ee0dd02ef247/src/runtime/malloc.go#L255-L276)
>
> The why it's happening is because of the go wrapper used to start vagrant. Because the VIRT you see is simply a reservation and not actually allocated, it's not a problem and not something that should be worried about.
>
> (There are some interesting conversations on the golang ML around the pros and cons of this approach, all pretty great reads).

It's just a copy/paste (and bolded the TLDR), hope it could help someone else.